# Refresh Listview with new Data after tab change doesn't work (Android)

Tags: android, listview, refresh, reload, baseadapter

I have a problem with refreshing my ListViews. I have a TabActivity calling another TabActivity(SubTabActivity) calling a ListActivity.
My ListView gets Data from an XML file from a Webserver.
In my Customized Header I have a Button to reload/ refresh the ListView.
When I change the subTab I call the onTabChanged-Method to redraw the List with other Data.

My problem now is I can refresh the ListView only before I make the first Tab Change. After I changed the Tap I can only refresh the second list. When I move back to the first list I can't refresh both. I can only get new data from my XML file but i can't show it.
I tried out to invalidate(), invalidateViews() and notifyDataSetChanged() but nothing could fix this bug.

my AsyncTask to refresh

```
private static class ReloadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{   
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        MenuActivity.startProgress();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        News.getNews(News.url);

        myref.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                if(SubTabMenuActivity.subMenuTabHost.getCurrentTabTag().equals("FestivalNews"))
                {
                    adapter = new NewsAdapter(myref, News.getFestivalNews());
                    newsList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else if(SubTabMenuActivity.subMenuTabHost.getCurrentTabTag().equals("RennNews"))
                {
                    adapter = new NewsAdapter(myref, News.getRegattaNews());
                    newsList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }   
        });     
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        MenuActivity.stopProgress();
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work after a TabChange?

**EDIT:**

```
10-25 05:58:28.264: D/dalvikvm(272): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 51% free 2725K/5511K,   external 410K/517K, paused 241ms
10-25 05:58:33.104: D/dalvikvm(310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 236K, 45% free 3366K/6087K, external 410K/517K, paused 53ms
10-25 05:58:35.281: D/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-25 05:58:38.163: D/dalvikvm(345): GC_EXPLICIT freed 106K, 44% free 3521K/6215K, external 410K/517K, paused 79ms
10-25 05:58:43.153: D/dalvikvm(360): GC_EXPLICIT freed 325K, 51% free 2720K/5511K, external 410K/517K, paused 54ms
10-25 05:58:57.233: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.243: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.263: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.273: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.273: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.293: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.303: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.313: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.323: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.333: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.333: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.433: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.453: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.483: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.493: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1274K, 62% free 3322K/8647K, external 2400K/2689K, paused 4ms+5ms
10-25 05:58:57.523: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.533: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.533: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.553: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.563: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.573: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.593: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.593: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.603: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.623: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.633: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.643: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.653: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.663: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.663: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.693: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.693: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.693: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.713: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.723: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.733: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.743: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.743: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.793: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.803: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.813: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:57.813: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.813: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.933: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.933: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:57.943: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.003: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_CONCURRENT freed 890K, 61% free 3439K/8647K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 8ms+4ms
10-25 05:58:58.003: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.003: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.013: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.013: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.023: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.073: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.073: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.083: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.083: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.103: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.113: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.113: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.123: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.123: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.143: I/System.out(433): ADaPter
10-25 05:58:58.433: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.453: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.453: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-25 05:58:58.453: D/skia(433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

This is my LogCat normal while filling the list and when I call refresh before a tabchange.

The following logcat part is after a tabchange and calling refresh again.

```
10-25 05:59:01.493: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 293K, 58% free 3686K/8647K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 30ms
10-25 05:59:01.493: I/dalvikvm-heap(433): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.655MB for 524304-byte allocation
10-25 05:59:01.523: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 256K, 58% free 3942K/9223K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 31ms
10-25 05:59:01.923: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 532K, 56% free 4094K/9223K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 27ms
10-25 05:59:02.313: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_CONCURRENT freed 862K, 54% free 4319K/9223K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 5ms+6ms
10-25 05:59:02.943: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_CONCURRENT freed 989K, 51% free 4609K/9223K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 7ms+3ms
10-25 05:59:03.473: D/dalvikvm(433): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1478K, 52% free 4447K/9223K, external 2240K/2689K, paused 7ms+7ms
10-25 05:59:03.783: W/InputManagerService(60): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4073bca0
```

I noticed that the adapter doesn't load the data into the List. If I call adapter.count(); I can see that he already got the new Data but he doesn't draw it to the List anymore.

After adding another logTag I noticed the the Constructor of my Adapter is called but not the getView method. Is it possible that my ListView looses the focus from the Adapter?

Comment: Are you sure your ReloadNews task is called after tab switch?

Comment: The ReloadNews Task is only called onButtonClick so i'm sure that the tab switched.

Comment: the listView lost it's focus but that's not the problem. The Adapters getView isn't called after a tab change and receiving new data. I don't understand why?!

Answer (score 0):

After

```
 newsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Add this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Good luck

Comment: I tried already this solution but it doesn't worked. But Thx for the answer.

Comment: Did you tried set null on setAdapter before create the new adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found my own solution. I've splited the different lists to different Activtiys and für each mainTab I created an own subTab Activity. 
I'm not proud of this solution but it works.